# Vertical center aligning pictures and minipages using subfig

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, subfloats, include

I am trying to place 3 sub numbered picture beside 3 unnumbered table and have each picture center aligned with one of the tables. For this I am using the `subfig` package and minipages to put the tables in, otherwise they get numbered or the pictures are numbered a c e instead of a b c.

To make it easier for me to write I made a command that includes the picture if it can be found and a minipage with an error text if it can not. When the picture is not found the center alignment works fine, figure 1, but when it is the bottom of the picture is aligned with the center of the table, figure 2.

How can I solve this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\includegraphicsmaybe}[2]{\IfFileExists{#2}{\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}}{\fbox{\parbox[c][#1][c]{#1}{\center \textbf{File not found}\\ #2} }}}



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!bt]
\centering
\subfloat[][Single-phase]{\includegraphicsmaybe{.4\textwidth}{../Pictures/SingleTrafo.jpg}\label{fig:SingleTrafo}}
\begin{minipage}[c][][c]{.5\textwidth}
    \hspace{5mm}\begin{tabular}{| r l |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{\textbf{Specifications}} \\
    \hline
    Power & 800 VA \\
    Frequency & 50 -- 60 Hz \\
    Primary & 127 -- 220 V \\
    Secondary & 127 V / 5.2 A \\
    Tertiary & 42 -- 73 V / 1.8 A \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\\
\subfloat[][Three-phase three-legged]{\includegraphicsmaybe{.4\textwidth}{../Pictures/3LegTrafo.jpg}\label{fig:3LegTrafo}}
\begin{minipage}[c][][c]{.5\textwidth}
    \hspace{5mm}\begin{tabular}{| r l |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{\textbf{Specifications}} \\
    \hline
    Power & 2400 VA \\
    Frequency & 50 -- 60 Hz \\
    Primary & 127 -- 220 V \\
    Secondary & 127 V / 5.2 A \\
    Tertiary & 42 -- 73 V / 1.8 A \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\\
\subfloat[][Three-phase five-legged]{\includegraphicsmaybe{.4\textwidth}{../Pictures/5LegTrafo.jpg}\label{fig:5LegFrafo}}
\begin{minipage}[c][][c]{.5\textwidth}
    \hspace{5mm}\begin{tabular}{| r l |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{\textbf{Specifications}} \\
    \hline
    Power & 2400 VA \\
    Frequency & 50 -- 60 Hz \\
    Primary & 127 -- 220 V \\
    Secondary & 127 V / 5.2 A \\
    Tertiary & 42 -- 73 V / 1.8 A \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\caption{transformers.}
\label{fig:Trafos}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image: Picture not found, Aligning]
Figure 1

[image: Picture found, not aligning]
Figure 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [`adjustbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) to your preamble with the `export` option, and use

```
\includegraphics[valign=c,..]{...}
```

Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\includegraphicsmaybe}[2]{%
  \IfFileExists{#2}
    {\includegraphics[valign=c,width=#1]{#2}}
    {\fbox{\parbox[c][#1][c]{#1}{\centering\textbf{File not found}\\ #2} }}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!bt]
  \centering
  \subfloat[][Single-phase]{\includegraphicsmaybe{.4\textwidth}{example-image-a}}
  \begin{minipage}[c][][c]{.5\textwidth}
    \hspace{5mm}\begin{tabular}{| r l |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{\textbf{Specifications}} \\
    \hline
    Power & 800 VA \\
    Frequency & 50 -- 60 Hz \\
    Primary & 127 -- 220 V \\
    Secondary & 127 V / 5.2 A \\
    Tertiary & 42 -- 73 V / 1.8 A \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}

  \subfloat[][Three-phase three-legged]{\includegraphicsmaybe{.4\textwidth}{example-image-b}}
  \begin{minipage}[c][][c]{.5\textwidth}
    \hspace{5mm}\begin{tabular}{| r l |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{\textbf{Specifications}} \\
    \hline
    Power & 2400 VA \\
    Frequency & 50 -- 60 Hz \\
    Primary & 127 -- 220 V \\
    Secondary & 127 V / 5.2 A \\
    Tertiary & 42 -- 73 V / 1.8 A \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}

  \subfloat[][Three-phase five-legged]{\includegraphicsmaybe{.4\textwidth}{example-image-c}}
  \begin{minipage}[c][][c]{.5\textwidth}
    \hspace{5mm}\begin{tabular}{| r l |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{\textbf{Specifications}} \\
    \hline
    Power & 2400 VA \\
    Frequency & 50 -- 60 Hz \\
    Primary & 127 -- 220 V \\
    Secondary & 127 V / 5.2 A \\
    Tertiary & 42 -- 73 V / 1.8 A \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{transformers.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```